# How to get output of 'git describe' into Jenkins build name

Tags: jenkins

What's the best (or any!) way to put the output of a command in a Jenkins build name?

I'd like to put the output of the `git describe` command into the build name of a Jenkins job.

I've installed the `build-name-setter` plugin with the hopes of setting the build name to something like:

```
${ENV, var="GIT_DESCRIBE"}
```

I just don't know how to set `$GIT_DESCRIBE` before the name is set!  I've tried using the `EnvInject` plugin.  The only way to dynamically set the environment variables is to use groovy script.  This would work well, except my job is running on a remote slave and the groovy script is (apparently) running only on the master.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need the "describe" data (i.e. you can't just use the existing `$GIT_BRANCH` or `$GIT_COMMIT` environment variables), you could add an "Execute shell step" with:

```
echo GIT_DESCRIBE=$(git describe) > git.properties
```

Then after that, add an EnvInject build step which injects properties from the `git.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following the steps outlined by Christopher Orr but my "Execute shell" script seemed to only run after the build had started. In my case GIT_DESCRIBE was never set/injected in time for the build to use it.

After some time researching I found a solution using the "Evaluated Groovy script" step as part of the Environment Injector Plugin. The Groovy script is evaluated pre-build. The main caveat there though is that the .groovy script is not run in the $WORKSPACE. What I ended up doing was executing a shell script located in my app ($WORKSPACE) from the .groovy script and returning its output as a map with GIT_DESCRIBE.

Evaluated Groovy script

```
def sout = new StringBuilder()
def serr = new StringBuilder()
def proc = "$WORKSPACE/git-describe.sh".execute()
proc.waitForProcessOutput(sout, serr)
def map = [GIT_DESCRIBE: sout.toString()]
return map
```

git-describe.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

# change working directory to the current script's directory
cd "${0%/*}"

echo `git describe`
```

From there you should be able to reference GIT_DESCRIBE in your "Build name" macro.

```
${ENV, var="GIT_DESCRIBE"}
```

Comment: Not tested (yet), but `git -C $WORKSPACE describe` should work just fine, no need for the extra script.

Answer (score 0):

With [build-name-setter](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) plugin v1.6.7 one could do the following:

- "Execute shell" build step, which does `git describe >version.txt`
- "Update build name" build step, which takes build name from `version.txt`.